# Color Property not accepting in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, option-type, uicolor

```
var frameColorInfo  = [String:UIColor]()
frameColorInfo["frameColor"] = logs.frameColor
frameColorInfo["matColor"] = logs.matColor

// To store frame Color things
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("FrameColorThings", object:frameColorInfo)

let frameColor:[UIColor]
let matColor:[UIColor]

frameColor: [UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.92549 0.92549 0.92549 1]
matColor: [UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.92549 0.92549 0.92549 1]
```

**I got the error:**

> Cannot assign value of type `[UIColor]` to type `UIColor?`

Comment: `logs.frameColor` is probably an Array and not a `UIColor`. Update your question with relevant info

Comment: @Shubhank : i trying to store in  color in frameColorInfo Array

Comment: update your question with how frameColor is declared in its source file

Comment: @Shubhank: i update the question

Comment: please update how it is declared instead of the logs

Comment: @Shubhank : i updated

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment comments if you use arrays. Do not use object as user info

```
var frameColorInfo  = [String:UIColor]()
frameColorInfo["frameColor"] = logs.frameColor//.first
frameColorInfo["matColor"] = logs.matColor//.first
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("FrameSizeThings", object: nil, userInfo: frameColorInfo)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the `frameColor` and `matColor` as an Array of `[UIColor]` which i think is simply a logical mistake from your side.

`[String:UIColor]` expects the element to be `UIColor` instead of an Array.

Try changing there declaration to

```
let frameColor:UIColor?
let matColor:UIColor?
```

and then use in your code

```
var frameColorInfo  = [String:UIColor]()
// do optionally checking if you want here 
frameColorInfo["frameColor"] = logs.frameColor!
frameColorInfo["matColor"] = logs.matColor!
```